# Product attribute on Checkout page summary magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to display the product attribute on checkout summary

currently i am using " MageVision_Blog16 " Extension

https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/get-a-product-attribute-in-checkout-summary-magento-2/

Its only showing the product attribute on checkout shipping information page but its not showing on Checkout payment page.. Can you give me an idea on how to display the product attribute on both..??

Answer (score 0):

Please check again the updated [post](https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/get-a-product-attribute-in-checkout-summary-magento-2/). In payment step the totalData array is set again only with the Magento's default quote total values, so the quoteItemData array has to be used to set the product's manufacturer and display it in checkout order summary in both steps.